# Provisioning Profile changed expiration date automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-enterprise

I have some question about iOS provisioning profiles for iOS Universal Distribution.

For what I know, a provisioning profile, when it's renewed or generated, it's validity is 1 year.

But somehow, until yesterday I had a provisioning profile with expiration date setted with 12 May 2017, but today from my developer app account, I see the provisioning profile with expiration date set with 25 May 2017.

As I know, it's no possible to change it manually, and it incremented only with 13 days.

How can it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may have created a new profile somehow. Maybe by regenerating your certificates or by deleting your profile in apple member center and fixing code signing issue in Xcode.

That latter happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a new profile at any time.  It will simply be set to expire a year from when you re-generated it.  If you didn't do it through the developer portal, it is most likely that you used the "Fix issue" button in Xcode while signed into your account.  That will sometimes invalidate certs and profiles and generate new ones.